# Поиск и замена слов после создания копии документа

Tags: google-apps-script

Суть такая есть некий Шаблон документа, при выполнении скрипта этот шаблон копируется в определенную папку, далее в нем находятся определенные слова и меняются на нужные мне.

Вот с первой частью, я разобрался:

```
function copy(){
var targetFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("id шаблона");
var source = DriveApp.getFileById("id папки назначения");
var newFile = source.makeCopy("Копия", targetFolder);
}
```

Как туда прикрутить поиск и замену? Пробовал через

```
newFile.replaceText(Замена1, 12);
```

но не работает, подскажите плз.

з.ы. не пинайте особо я не программист от слово вообще :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам необходимо получить секцию, в которой вы будете призводить замену. Например `Body`

```
/**
 * @file Copy the template and replace text
 * @url https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1073978
 */

/**
 * Run the snippet
 */
function run() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var copy = copyAndReplace_(doc);
  Logger.log(copy);
}

/**
 *
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Document.Document} template
 * @return {GoogleAppsScript.Document.Document}
 */
function copyAndReplace_(template) {
  var copy = DriveApp.getFileById(template.getId()).makeCopy();
  var newDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
  newDoc.getBody().replaceText('\s', ' <trehe is a space> ');
  newDoc.saveAndClose();
  return newDoc;
}
```

- [Class Text / replaceText(searchPattern, replacement)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#replacetextsearchpattern,-replacement)
- [Сниппет](https://github.com/contributorpw/google-apps-script-snippets/blob/master/snippets/document-copy_and_replace/copy_and_replace.js)

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: @ПономаревАлександр, вы можете отметить вопрос как решенный.